# Css class styles aren't applied to svg

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have what bigger svg image and I want to wait until it is fully loaded to show it. Thus I first show a loader and then the svg.

The html code is as follows:

```
<section id="top-banner">
    <div id="spinner"><object data="/assets/img/spinner.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object> </div>
    <object id="svgbannerholder" data="/assets/img/banner.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
</section>
```

The css is as follows:

```
#svgbannerholder {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#spinner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  height: 623px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.test{
  display: none !important;
}
```

And the js file is as follows:

```
// wait until DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function () {
    // wait until window is loaded - all images, styles-sheets, fonts, links, and other media assets
    $(window).on("load", function () {
        var spinner = $("#spinner");
        var svgholder = $("#svgbannerholder");
        var car_to_inspection = document.getElementById("svgbannerholder").contentDocument.getElementById("i10");

        svgholder.load("image/svg+xml", function () {
            spinner.addClass("hidden"); // hide spinner
            svgholder.css("opacity", 1); // show svg with fadein animation


            car_to_inspection.classList.add("test");
            // car_to_inspection.style.display = "none";
        });
    });

});
```

After the svg is loaded I'm trying to apply animation to an element. But the problem is that the styles of the class aren't applied. The class self is added to right element, but it isn't applied.

[image]

If I add the style directly via javascript as for example `car_to_inspection.style.display = "none";`, then it is applied.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: If you are using chrome i was running into this issue the other day except I was trying to add a pattern to a `<use>` declaration dynamically in javascript. My pattern url would show up but not the patterned shape. For me it was a bug, but my styles always showed up because I used inline `<style>` tag instead of classes. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<object id="svgbannerholder" ...>` contains its own document (you actually access it by `contentDocument`). It means that it has its own CSS rules, and your class `.test` is not defined in your contentDocument, but in the main page.

You can add the class declaration in your .svg file, directly inserting a `<style>` tag in the xml (inside the `<svg>` tag, not outside), or apply inline styles directly without using classes. I haven't tried to insert dynamically the `<style>` tag to the contentDocument afterwards, but it should work too.

Comment: I can't add class declaration to a svg file, because I use mixins. And that is why I can't insert `<style>` tag directly. But I've removed `<object>` tag and I've inserted svg file directly in the html page. And now it works, the styles are applied. But is that a smart approach?

Comment: if your svg image is fixed and not supposed to by dynamic, i see no reason it couldn't be included directly in the html page